# How to remove the underscore from DLL export

Tags: c++, c, dll, dllexport, name-decoration

I want to replace a DLL for which I don't have the full source code (but the function declarations). The application loads this DLL at runtime and calls `GetProcAddress` with (all) the function names. (so I have to name the functions exactly the same).

I created a new DLL (in MS VC2013) and wrote the functions. But I have a problem exporting them correctly.

In the original DLL they are defined with `_stdcall` but their names don't start with an underscore.

If I specify the name in the .def file like this `testfunc@4=testfunc` everything behind the @ is removed.

How can I specify in VS2013 that I want an DLL-export like `testfunc@4`?

Comment: Have you tried exporting them as `extern "C"` ?

Comment: I vaguely remember this to be a problem but can't repro on VS2013.  It should be `testfunc@4 = _testfunc@4`  Without the @ on the right-hand side, the @4 is interpreted as the ordinal.

Comment: extern "c" removed all decoration (what is not what i want - i need the @4 at the end; And if i specify the line you mention in the .def file the linker seems to strip everything away after the "@"

Comment: Original DLL was probably created by GCC or one of its variations.

Comment: It may be noteworthy that it's not possible to `extern "C"` when compiling pure C units (.c). Hence the popular `#ifdef __cplusplus` check prior to using it. But if you're compiling C, that export decoration is inevitable.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I think is by adding

```
// in cpp, but will probably work in header too
#pragma comment(linker, "/export:FunctionName@4=_FunctionName@4")

// in header
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall FunctionName(int param);
```

in the source code of your DLL.

I got the idea from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/exports?view=msvc-160). They also explain how to do it with a DEF file. A matter of taste I guess. You will end up with two entries for the same function in the export table but the application should be able to get the correct proc address.

Comment: Thank you very much - great tip, +1. I am wondering why that answer hasn't got a lot of upvotes yet.